# Merge schema with missing structure in spark

Tags: python, pyspark, schema

I'm using a script in pyspark to merge data.
The normal behavior and structure of the data is as such:
`array<struct<amount:double,commission:double,commissionUnit:string,description:string,soldPrice:double,type:string>>`

The "normal" data that I normally gather is :
[image: Normal data]

However I recently found a new example of the data that I cannot use with that schema:
`array<struct<amount:bigint,description:string,type:string>>`

[image: example of data]

I am using the first schema in the following piece of code in order to cast properly the data ingested:

```py
df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(field.dataType))
```

Unfortunately when I try to apply the first schema to the latest example, I end up with  the following error :
`cannot resolve 'lines' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast array<struct<amount:bigint,description:string,type:string>> to array<struct<amount:double,commission:double,commissionUnit:string,description:string,soldPrice:double,type:string>>;`

In the end, as the lines column is an array of structtype, it can happen that both those examples coexist in the same array.

I have actually no clue how to make sure that I can cast correctly the data in both examples in one shot using the first schema. The end result should be the first schema with null values where the structfields were empty.

EDIT:
I found out that I can apply the following schema when there are a batch of data (multiple row with different format for the `lines` field)

```py
ArrayType(
StructType([
StructField("amount", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("comission", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("commissionUnit", StringType(), True),
StructField("description", StringType(), True),
StructField("soldPrice", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("type", StringType(), True)
])
)
```

The error only occur when applying the schema for a single row where the `lines` schema differs from the schema I try to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, spark expected all of the schema fields to be present while you don't have it in the case you showed

pretty straightforward forward I guess, so once we understand the problem, let's solve it.

So first thing, you will have to create the schema on your own.
This way you will control the incoming input, the required fields and won't have any future surprises unless it breaks your basic schema.

So, according to the information you provided let's create the schema:

```py
MyExpectedSchema = ArrayType(
StructType([
StructField("amount", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("comission", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("commissionUnit", StringType(), True),
StructField("description", StringType(), True),
StructField("soldPrice", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("type", StringType(), True)
])
)
```

The schema we defined above is the general schema you expected, but here we said that we allow them to be nulls (all the "True" arguments within the struct field)

This way we can accept any of them to be present or not.

**Note**: If you have any field that you know for a fact it's required not to be null, remove the `True`. BUT be aware that in case it won't be delivered the casting will fail.

So to sum up, now you can use your line

```
df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(field.dataType))
```

But instead cast using what we declared above.

```
df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(MyExpectedSchema))
```

Don't forget to import all of the types from `pyspark.sql.types`

Comment: Hello Benny. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this solution is not working. In the `field.dataType`, I'm already giving the expected schema.

Comment: No The datatype of the field is vary between these two struct types. You should put the extended version to br always present, and the True to allow nulls. Thats way it must work.

Comment: Here is an example for which this fails: 
`spark.createDataFrame([["_"]],["col"]).select(F.struct().withField("a", sf.lit("A")).cast(T.StructType([T.StructField("a", st.StringType(), True), T.StructField("b", st.StringType())]))).show()
`